# Wifi keeps disconnecting due to an Operation state change request on the interface

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, connection

Not sure why but my WIFI randomly gets disconnected with not much information just two events in Event Viewer, if more information is required I will provide it.

First is this event.

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig
Date:          5/18/2021 12:45:18 PM
Event ID:      11004
Task Category: MsmSecurity
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (1024),(512)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      LAPTOP
Description:
Wireless security stopped.

Network Adapter: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
Network SSID: WIFIHOME
BSS Type: Infrastructure
Security Hint: The operation was successful.
```

Then this one.

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig
Date:          5/18/2021 12:45:18 PM
Event ID:      8003
Task Category: AcmConnection
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (1073741824),(1024),(512)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      LAPTOP
Description:
WLAN AutoConfig service has successfully disconnected from a wireless network.

Network Adapter: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
Connection Mode: Automatic connection with a profile
Profile Name: WIFIHOME
SSID: WIFIHOME
BSS Type: Infrastructure
Reason: The network is disconnected due to an Operation state change request on this interface
```

I haven't done anything to my WIFI driver and it's fully updated.

**Specs:**

Device: Asus GL504GW
OS: Windows 10 Pro 20H2 19042.985
WIFI: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz

Comment: Is the PC hibernating or suspending?, This will cause 8003 event id.

Comment: @Moab nope not at all i am like playing a game and it just disconnects

Comment: Any recent windows updates? That match the time when this started?

Comment: @Moab the latest update i installed was KB5003173 which the problem has happened even before that

Comment: Don't read too much into that log message. It may be that the AP kicked you off, and when the driver reported that change to the OS, this is what the OS logged. It makes it sound like the software *requested* to leave the AP's network, but that may not have been the case; I suspect the AP kicked you off. You might need an 802.11 monitor-mode packet trace to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: @Spiff I will see if my network adapter works with that but also I got this problem too sometimes https://superuser.com/questions/1631343/ics-causing-wifi-to-keep-losing-connection-on-windows-10 are they related at all also I use a android phone as my hotspot